# Compare CSV File Records with Python Scrapy Output Data

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm new to Python and web scraping. Pls excuse me for my ignorance. In this program, I have crawled some urls and saved product name and price to csv file. When I run the script again, I want to read the existing csv records(product name and price) and  if there's a change of the price for any product/s, I want to print a message. I'm struggling with implementing 2nd part of the program, Which is compare values against saved csv records. Please help. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
import scrapy
from time import sleep
import csv, os, json
import random
import os

class spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider1"

    with open("data.csv", "a") as filee:

        if os.stat("data.csv").st_size != 0:
            filee.truncate(0)
        filee.close()

    def start_requests(self):
        list = ["https://www.example.com/item1",
                "https://www.example.com/item2",
                "https://www.example.com/item3",
                "https://www.example.com/item4",
                "https://www.example.com/item5"
                ]

        for i in list:
            yield scrapy.Request(i, callback=self.parse)
            sleep(random.randint(0, 5))

    def parse(self, response):

        product_name = response.css('#pd-h1-cartridge::text')[0].extract()
        product_price = response.css(
            '.product-price .is-current, .product-price_total .is-current, .product-price_total ins, .product-price ins').css(
            '::text')[3].extract()


        with open('data.csv', 'a+') as file:

            itemwriter = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

            itemwriter.writerow([str(product_name).strip(), str(product_price).strip()])

            file.close()
```

---

CSV Output

```
Purple Wine Glass Cooler,1.47
Color Your Own VBS Island Wind Chimes,6.47
Color Your Own Fuzzy Patriotic Wreaths,7.79
Color Your Own Patriotic Keychains,6.19
Patriotic Cool Treats Craft Stick Magnet Craft Kit,6.19
```

Comment: I would do two separated programs/scripts - first to scrape data to new csv and second to compare values in two csv files.

Comment: if you do `filee.truncate(0)` then you lose previous data and then you can't compare them with new values.

Comment: scrapy has built-in function to write in csv. You can run it with option `-o data.csv` or `-t csv -o data.csv`.

Comment: @furas Thanx for the tips. If I used two scripts, I ll have to crawl pages 2x times. I want to run this script as a cron job only 1 - 2 times a day.

Comment: no, you don't have to crawl 2x times. You have to crawl once at start to get first data, and later (in cron) you have to crawl once a day to get new data which you compare with previous data. Second script is used only to compare data in two csv files which you have on disk, not to scrape new data.

Comment: if you want to do it in one script then you have to read values from `data.csv` before you use `truncate()` and then you can compare them with new values which you get in `parse()`

Comment: @furas Thanx. I'm gonna try last 2 tips. 2 scripts method should work in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Scrapy to generate CSV files only.

Write a separate script to compare CSV files.